# Ubuntu Server 15.10, autologin?

Tags: server, login, 15.10

I'm trying to set up a home server for share printers and files, and I would like to enable auto login at startup, but anything of what I found on the internet worked. Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: http://ubuntuguide.net/boot-into-text-mode-and-login-automatically worked for me the last time I needed it (was 14.04 and not a lot has changed since then regarding the base system).

Comment: I can't find /etc/init/tty1.conf

Answer (score 3):

I edited the symbolic link in `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service` adding the `--autologin` param to `agetty`.  This way:

```
ExecStart=/sbin/agetty --noclear --autologin <username> %I $TERM
```

I hope it helps o/

Comment: Yes, it works for Ubuntu wily 15.10. Thanks!