# Direct script execution on Ubuntu Server 15.10 skipping login screen

Tags: server, bash, 15.10, automation

I need to execute script automatically on boot and display its output on screen but I have two problems.

- Ubuntu asks login credentials
- How do I get script display output on screen (to work as in terminal, just simple echo functions).

This all needs work without needing a single button to be pressed.

Questions are:

1. Is this even possible?
2. If it is, how?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you need the GUI afterwards?

Comment: No,no gui required

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here:

1. Auto-login to a command line session
2. Keeping the output of the script after its execution

I think the first problem can be solved like explained here: [How to autologin (without entering username and password)(in text mode)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175248/how-to-autologin-without-entering-username-and-passwordin-text-mode)

You have multiple options for the second problem.

**Option 1: storing the output of the script in a text file, and displaying it at login**

In order to do that, you need to redirect the output of the script to a file. You can do that by adding `> /path/to/file` when you invoke the script.

```
./yourscript.sh > /tmp/myOutput
```

Then, you add the following line into your `~/.bashrc` file (create it if it does not exist), asking bash to read that file when you login:

```
cat /tmp/myOutput
```

The output of the last execution of the startup script should now be displayed each time you log into the system.

**Option 2: using tmux (terminal multiplexer)**

You can run the execution of the script inside a [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) session, and then, at login time, attach to that session. That way, you'll have the history of the execution.

Tmux is easily installable on Ubuntu with `apt-get install tmux`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/689870/ubuntu-server-15-10-autologin